# How do I fix my code so I can receive simple socket strings to my app

Tags: java, android, python, sockets

My java code will not print in the textbox the string it received from a python server (but it can send strings to the server)

everything else is working but I am setting the receiving end on the app wrong

```
   try {
            String hosty = "xxx.xxx.x.xx";
            int porty = xxxxx;
            s = new Socket(hosty,porty);
            pw = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream());
            pw.write(message);
            pw.flush();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));

            if( bufferedReader.ready() )
            {
                logy = bufferedReader.readLine();   //rcv as jason
            }
            else
            {
                logy = null;
            }

            TextView txtView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView);
            txtView.setText(logy);




            pw.close();
            s.close();
```

And this is the relevant code on the python server

```
conn.send("testlettestlet\n".encode('utf-8'))
```

Comment: Why do you bother checking `bufferedReader.ready()`? You don't do anything sensible if it returns `false`. Just take that whole if statement out and replace it with `logy = bufferedReader.readLine();`

Comment: Thanks James. That solved it. However now it will hold at that point in the code indefinitely until a string is received. Is there to continue if there is no pending string being received?